# How are .dex files protected against patching?

Tags: java, android, dex

I am new to dealing with Android apps and their characteristics.
There is one thing I do not understand and so far I did not find an explanation for the observed behaviour:

I created a basic Android app in which a string is defined:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String s = new String("JustanExample");
    }
}
```

This app can be build and run in the Android Studio emulator without problems.

Now if I decompile the apk file with apktool, compile it, sign it and run it everything works fine as well.

```
$ apktool d -r -s app-test.apk
$ apktool b -f -d app-test
$ jarsigner -verbose -keystore my-test-key.keystore app-test/dist/app-test.apk alias_name
```

But if I decompile the apk, open the classes.dex file with a hex editor and change the "JustanExample" string to something else (e.g. "abcdanExample" - same length), compile it, sign it and install it, the app immediately stops/crashes.

```
$ apktool d -r -s app-test.apk

  change the string in the classes.dex with hex editor

$ apktool b -f -d app-test
$ jarsigner -verbose -keystore my-test-key.keystore app-test/dist/app-test.apk alias_name
```

Is the .dex file protected against patching attempts?
How and can it be bypassed?

**Update 01:** Based on the suggestion of David Kroukamp, I had a look at the logcat output (com.example.helloworld is the name of the app). It seems like it is an checksum issue:

```
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.helloworld-KxRtzkSSxWpFrHOn_7pXEQ==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.helloworld-KxRtzkSSxWpFrHOn_7pXEQ==/base.apk': Bad checksum (fce4124d, expected e273124a)
```

Based on reading some first search results, it seems like the checksum is stored in the dex file itself. I am going to do some further reading to see if I can find a way of making my patched dex files work.

**Update 02:** If I replace the checksum in the header of the dex file with the one that I obtain from the logcat output I obtain a different error output:

```
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.helloworld-QNglYY_UVQvVT-7uwN4dhA==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.helloworld-QNglYY_UVQvVT-7uwN4dhA==/base.apk': Out-of-order string_ids: 'abcdanExample' then 'KEEP_ALIVE'
```

In addition, I get an additional message in both previous situation that differs only slightly:

checksum not patched:

```
2020-12-28 12:34:45.110 7106-7106/com.example.helloworld E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.helloworld-YMa5lJJ4Vva3eQZ0chGS4Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.helloworld-YMa5lJJ4Vva3eQZ0chGS4Q==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64]]
```

checksum patched:

```
2020-12-28 12:39:33.644 7481-7481/com.example.helloworld E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.helloworld-QNglYY_UVQvVT-7uwN4dhA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.helloworld-QNglYY_UVQvVT-7uwN4dhA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64]]
```

**Current solution**
For the time being, I now use the workflow described at https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/9185.
It works for me.

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried to get the error via the Logcat while the device is running and connected to your Android Studios?

Comment: This was a good idea. It seems like there is a checksum of the dex file: Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.helloworld-KxRtzkSSxWpFrHOn_7pXEQ==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.helloworld-KxRtzkSSxWpFrHOn_7pXEQ==/base.apk': Bad checksum (fce4124d, expected e273124a)

Answer (score 0):

out of order string_ids means -
the string_ids section of dex file is list of strings that are used as names/constant/class names/method names/field names/.............
it is just a list. for example like-

1. aMethodName
2. LClass/bla/bla/MainActivity;
3. onCreate
4. network error!

etc.
where ever these strings are needed, they just use the index of that list item.
for example, the onCreate() method (in methodSection) will just keep number "3" as methodName.
so every thing in dex file is referenced via item index.
that way, dex file wont get bigger because same string is not stored again and again.

this string section (and other sections too,) has two rules.

1. all items should be in alphabetical order.
2. all items should be unique.

so when you replace some string, you are editing the stringSection. because its the only place where strings appears.(all other places has its index only)

but by editing, you are disturbing its alphabetical order.